# Neovim keybinding for LSP "code action" with options

Tags: neovim

I use neovim and `neovim-lsp-config` with clangd.

The default keybind for code actions is `<space>ca`, after pressing which a menu pops up. Usually there is just one option, so having to choose it from the menu feels laborious. Luckily, [the documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html) states that you can pass a boolean flag `apply`, so that when there is just one option it is selected automatically.

So I tried to change the keybinding to following:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>ca', function()
    vim.lsp.buf.code_action({apply=true}) end, bufopts)
```

But the behavior does not change - the menu still appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The question has been answered here: https://neovim.discourse.group/t/neovim-keybinding-for-lsp-code-action-with-options/3052